# Excel conditional number formats with negative numbers

Tags: excel

I need a number format that displays numbers between -1 and 1 green, and the ones outside this interval red.I want two decimal digits.

I have tried,

```
"[RED][<-1]#,##0.00;[RED][>1]#,##0.00;[GREEN]#,##0.00"
```

but then e.g. -0.3 is displayed as 0.30.
How can I preserve the signs of negative numbers between -1 and 0?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to force 2 decimal places or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the negative on the correct one:

```
[RED][<-1]-#,##0.00;[RED][>1]#,##0.00;[GREEN]#,##0.00
```

Comment: This now displays e.g. -2 as --2.00, but -0.3 is till displayed as 0.30. I am using LIbreOffice Version: 6.0.4.2

Comment: @user10178557 Then why did you ask this question on the excel tag?! This answer is correct for Excel. Upped.

Comment: Indeed it is. Sorry, wrongly assumed that number formats work the same way.